# How to definitively change a parameter in a xml vm domain file?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virsh, debian-jessie

I have a vm with the machine type = "pc-012". For a reason linked with virtio, I changed the machine type for "pc-1.1" with **virsh edit domain** command.

When I reboot the host, I find again "pc-012" !?

How to change definitively the parameter ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: Did you shut down the VM?

Comment: yes I did: I stopped the vm, edited the xml, reboot the machine. Easy to reproduce

Comment: If it's Debian, who knows? Try another distribution.

Comment: Debian or libvirt ! do you know where libvirt find the machine type ?

Comment: I probably made a big error just now: I stopped libvirtd, delete the /var/cache/libvirt/qemu/capabilities folder and restarted libvirtd. Now I cannot start my virtual machines, I cannot access to the xml files by virsh edit. Do you know how to "regenerate" the qemu capabilities or start libvirtd without the cache ?

Comment: forget my last message: the /var folder was full !!!!!

Comment: My vm was created under Wheezy and now I am under Jessie. I suspect that is the reason. If I create a new vm, the machine type is not anymore pc-0.12 but pc-i440fx-2.1 and if I reboot the machine then the vm file keeps this value ! Therefore, the question becomes how to adapt an "old vm file" ?

Comment: Finally the work around is to create a clone of the vm,then swap the clone and the original.